# CountDistinct() based on few columns

Tags: pyspark, group-by, count

Let's say my dataframe in PySpark looks like this:

```
cats | letter| pet
--------------------
cat1 | A     | cat
cat1 | A     | dog
cat2 | B     | cat
cat2 | B     | cat
cat2 | A     | cat
cat1 | B     | cat
cat1 | B     | dog
```

I would like to group by cats so that I can count distinct over letter and pet. Meaning if those two columns are the same for specific cats - there are dupliactes and I don't count them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`countDistinct` should help you as below-

```scala
 df1.groupBy("cats").agg(countDistinct("letter", "pet"))
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +----+---------------------------+
      * |cats|count(DISTINCT letter, pet)|
      * +----+---------------------------+
      * |cat1|4                          |
      * |cat2|2                          |
      * +----+---------------------------+
      */
```